# How to uninstall Libreoffice Base only from ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall, libreoffice

I have LiberOffice on my Ubuntu (Writer-calc-impress-draw)
I was trying to update LibreOffice by using this command:
sudo apt-get upgrade libreoffice
so I find that I have new installed app which is (Base),
and the old apps from LiberOffice did not updated.
Now I want to uninstall **Base Only** ?

thanks

Comment: sudo apt purge liberoffice-base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall libreoffice-base open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt remove libreoffice-base
sudo apt reinstall libreoffice-core libreoffice-common libreoffice-writer
```